# Android. Разрешение установки приложений через USB

Tags: android, отладка, usb, установка

При попытке включения установки через USB (нажатие на кнопку "Установка через USB Разрешить установку приложений через USB") телефон требует вставить SIM-карту.

[image: Нажатие на кнопку "Установка через USB Разрешить установку приложений через USB"]

В случае если при этом выключить вайфай и повторить нажатие (либо же включить режим полёта) то требуется подключится к сети.

[image: Нажатие с выключенным вайфаем]

**Примечание:** до недавнего момента всё работало нормально, приложения через USB устанавливались и без SIM-карты. Случайно выключил режим разработчика, настройки сбросились.

**Телефон**: Xiaomi Mi Max 32 GB

**Версия Android**: 7.0 NRD90M

**Версия MIUI**: MIUI Global 8.5 Стабильная 8.5.1.0(NBCMIED)

**Вопрос:** Как обратно включить установку через USB?

Comment: да у них там отладка разрешена только если заведен и залогинен их `Mi аккаунт`

Comment: Сейчас без симкарты вообще никак, хоть с ми аккаунтом, хоть без. Все равно симкарту требует